# Why I get this error when I try to use npm install -g ganache-cli truffle in vs code?

Tags: npm, ganache

Why I get this error when I try to use  `npm install -g ganache-cli truffle` in vs code?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio including the Desktop development with C++ workload. Remember Visual Studio is different from Visual Studio Code.

Basically workloads are like plugins and are easy to install once you have installed Visual Studio.

Comment: What I am telling you is written in the error.